# QGIS & PostGIS: Layer not valid - not loaded

Tags: postgis-2.0, qgis-2.16

I've been having some issues with PostGIS and QGIS.
I'm trying to connect to a PostGIS database, and retreive a layer called MargamParkMap (in Schema MargamPark)
[image: LayerList]
No warning triangle (like the views - I get why that is - no Primary key, that's not my problem) - should be fine right?

[image: WarningMessage]

Wrong.

Now - the error would appear to be because key="", rather than having an actual value. But the table has a primary key! [image: primarykey]
So - why is QGIS ignoring the primary key in the layer? It has one, why not use it!?

:EDIT:
For some reason, if I create a new project (not even close and reopen QGIS) it works.... But then sometimes, it doesnt, straight after it working.